# RFHUtil MQ utility tool not supporting TLSV1.2 Cipher to connect MQ-9

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I am not able to connect the WMQ-9.1 queue manager via RFHUtil in case the channel configured with TLSV1.2 Cipher means.

No issues when i am connecting from SSL to TLSV1.0 version in that.  Never tried TLSV1.1 before.

Any idea how to overcome this also can you suggest any alternate open source tools are available in the market or git repo?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what "not able to connect" looks like?  Do you receive an error from RFHUtil?  Do you receive any errors in the queue manager's  `AMQERR01.LOG` file?

Comment: RFHUtil (aka SupportPac IH03) has been withdrawn by IBM.  It does not support the latest SSL/TLS CipherSuites.  You should look at other tools like MQ Visual Edit.

Comment: One suggestion elsewhere has been to use a CCDT (client channel definition table) to define the use of TLS1.2 and then reference that from RFHUtil rather than configuring the connection in RFHUtil itself

Comment: Nov 20, 2018 10:16:06 AM MainWindow getTreeViewQueueManagerPopupMenu
SEVERE: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'.
Nov 20, 2018 1:12:44 PM MainWindow getTreeViewQueueManagerPopupMenu
SEVERE: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2538'.

Comment: Any type of configuration, source,  or errors should be edited into the question by clicking the edit button to the bottom left of the question.  In this case the error `2400` is `MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE`, which version of the MQ client do you have installed and which version of RFHUtil do you have?  On github IBM have source that needs to be compiled which lists only TLS1.2 ciphers in the dropdown.

Comment: Yes, Checked out the latest RFHUtile source from the GIT as it supports TLSV1.2

Comment: NGBeginner, you should write that up as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @JoshMc - Sure, will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull the latest from here.

https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-rfhutil/tree/master/bin/Release